# Magmi: No records found in datasource

Tags: magento2, magmi, import-products

Using magmi 0.7.24 for Magento 2.4
Importing one simple and configurable product
Placed the file in var/import
File is detected. I ran import and get the following output

```
Import Profile:default
Import Mode:create
Attributeset update is enabled.
Import Profile:default
Import Mode:create
Attributeset update is enabled.
Performing Datasource Lookup...
Found 0 records, took 1.6927719116211E-5 sec
```

In runtime infos I get `Initialized attribute_set_infos!`
In warning window it is showing `No Records returned by datasource`

I have selected Image attributes processor and columns mapper

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded to 0.7.23 and it resolved my issue.

0.7.24 is not working for some reason